# play a local Audio in android with Cordova/PhoneGap using Media plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio

I try to play a mp3 file. This works if I change the path to the file on my local webServer, but if I run this on an Android device the sound is not played and error is :`{"code":1}`

this is my code

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="playAudio('sounds/blop.mp3');">hi</button>
```

**javascript:**

```
function playAudio(src) {
    var url = src;
    var my_media = new Media(url,
            // success callback
             function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); },
            // error callback
             function (err) { console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
                            alert(JSON.stringify(err))
                            }
    );
           // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```

**config.xml:**

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media.git"/>
```

I tried

```
<button onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/sounds/blop.mp3');">hi</button>
```

and :

```
 <button onclick="playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/sounds/blop.mp3');">hi</button>
```

But its still does not work in Android:

[error :{"code":1}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp2xi.png)

is there any solution?!

### Edit 1 :

The is my *App structure*

```
App
`-- www
    `-- index.html
        |+-- sounds
        |   `-- blop.mp3
        |-- js
        `-- css
```

Comment: try out this sample app - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

I checked your project and the url passed works ok, I also tested the app and for some audio files you have wrong url set like:
"sounds/PopCork.mp3"

So the actual url that you need to pass is:
 "file:///android_asset/www/sounds/PopCork.mp3"

So to make this work cross platform use:

cordova.file.applicationDirectory + ''www/sounds/PopCork.mp3"

All the best with the project!

---

This line should work fine:

`<button onclick="playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/sounds/blop.mp3');">hi</button>`

could you plz paste www folder structure?

Comment: what is the cordova version you are using?

Comment: Cordova V = 7.0.1      ,